# Can the split environment be used for only one equation?

Tags: equations, split, gather

Within the span of half of a page, the User's Guide for the `amsmath` Package gives conflicting assertions about whether the `equation` or `align` or `gather` environment housing the `split` structure can contain only one equation or multiple equations.

[image: amsmath manual page 7]

Well, which is it?

Also, what is a good way to split multiple long equations in an `align` environment?

Here is an MWE try:
It has three equations, two of which have long right-hand-sides that need to be split over multiple lines. There should be only three equation numbers on the left side

```
\begin{align}
\framebox[0.3\columnwidth]{eqn 1 LHS} &=              \framebox[.4\columnwidth]{eqn 1 RHS 1}\\
                                      &\hphantom{=} + \framebox[.4\columnwidth]{eqn 1 RHS 2}\\
\framebox[.25\columnwidth]{eqn 2 LHS} &= \framebox[.35\columnwidth]{eqn 2 RHS}\\
\framebox[0.35\columnwidth]{eqn 3 LHS} &=              \framebox[.35\columnwidth]{eqn 3 RHS 1}\\
                                       &\hphantom{=} + \framebox[.35\columnwidth]{eqn 3 RHS 2}\\
\end{align}
```

[image: mwe try]

Comment: Can it be the only thing in any line of `align` environment?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: I don't see a conflict or contradiction between the sentences you highlighted in yellow and red. The first highlighted sentence says (correctly, in my view) that a `split` environment should contain the entire body of the enclosing "structure", while the second highlighted sentence implies (to my reading, at least) that a `gather` environment can contain more than one "structure" -- and hence more than one `split` environment.

Comment: Your question as to "what is a good way to split multiple long equations in an `align` environment" cannot be answered meaningfully without knowing the contents of the equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked,

> Can the `split` environment be used for only one equation?

Using the sentence you highlighted in yellow, I believe the answer should be

> A `split` environment should contain the entire body of the enclosing structure.

What may give rise to confusion is the term "structure". Consider the case of

```
a = b 
  = c
```

which I trust can be accepted as an example of a particular structure, *viz.*, a two-line equation. Now consider three different ways to typeset this two-line equation/structure.  The first uses `split`, with `split` enclosing the entire structure; the second uses `aligned`; and the third tries to mimic the second but with the use of `split`. The first two ways succeed, whereas the third quite obviously does not. Observe also that I could have placed the first two structures in independent `equation*` environments without provoking a change in the way the structures end up getting typeset.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\begin{split}  % this is ok
a &= b \\
  &= c 
\end{split}\\[1ex]
a \begin{aligned}[t] % this is ok too
  &= b \\
  &= c
  \end{aligned}
\end{gather*}

\[
a \begin{split} % this is not ok
  &= b \\
  &= c
  \end{split}
\]
\end{document}
```